# 3D GPU acceleration on AMD graphics with mesa drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, blender

I use Blender regularly for my work. I heard, recently, that you can use the more recent Radeon graphics cards for hardware acceleration and 3D GPU processing with only the mesa open-source driver. Is this  true? Does GPU processing work out of the box for Radeon cards with the built-in drivers in the Linux kernel & openCL, now?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used it myself, [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35969/935) indicates you will need `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` installed. Note that opencl is only used for cycles rendering and [compositing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/properties.html#performance).

Blender's UI is drawn using opengl and the mesa libraries will provide gpu acceleration for updating blender's window.